# how to exit from the loop in python

Tags: python, django

I'm looping all the rows and I want to return it but even after looping all the rows and even data is saving in the database but its not getting exit from it due to which I'm getting an error as `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`. I don't know where I'm going wrong

This what I tried

Views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
  if request.method == 'POST': 

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if request.data:
        for ran in  request.data:

            auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
            print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
            ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
            Agents = ran.get('Agents')
            Comments = ran.get('Comments')
            Supervisor = ran.get('Supervisor')
            

            sid = 0
            print('sid--', sid)
            qid = ran.get('QId')
            print('qid---', qid)
            answer = ran.get('Answer')

            cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s',
                                        (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid))
            result_st = cursor.fetchall()
            print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', result_st)

       
        for row in result_st:
            print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', row)
        return Response(row[0])
    
    print('after after')
    return Response(0)
```

Here, is the payload:

```
    [{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":42,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":43,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""},  

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":44,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":45,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":46,"Answer":"3","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 
{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":47,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":48,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":49,"Answer":"2","SID":"0","Comments":""}, 

{"AuditorId":130,"Agents":"","Supervisor":"","TicketId":"325423432","QId":50,"Answer":"5","SID":"0","Comments":""}]
```

Comment: at some point, `ran` must be a string instead of a more complex object (like a `dict`) that supports the `.get()` method. If that is unexpected, try just printing out the `ran` object to see what it is at all times

Comment: I have tried printing the `ran`  `ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId  ran--- AuditorId ran--- Auditor` and `Exception ignored in tp_clear of: <class 'AttributeError'>` in console it started printing once the dict ends @drootang. How could I fix this

Answer (score 0):

One of your request.data is not a dict but a string, to know where this wrong value appear, try something like :

```
if request.data:
    for index, ran in enumerate(request.data):

        if isInstance(if isinstance(element, dict)):
              // retrieve data
        else:
              print(str(index), ran)
```

Comment: Have tried but I don't find any issue in dict even I have check but found issue when I print  `request.data` it just  `ran ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId ran--- AuditorId  ran--- AuditorId ran--- Auditor` and `Exception ignored in tp_clear of: <class 'AttributeError'>` in console it started printing once the dict ends @tCot